# DRF: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "tickettype-detail"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We want our users to be able to define the options for various select fields in our site.  Those options will go in their own table (model).

For the API, we have the "Ticket" model. which has a field "type" which is a ForeignKey to the "TicketType" model.

I'm getting this error:

```
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view
name "tickettype-detail". You may have failed to include the
related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the
`lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

If I remove the type field from the Ticket model, the error goes away.  I've read a lot of posts online about this, and tried a lot of different things, but so far haven't been able to fix it.

**models.py:**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Ticket(models.Model):
    summary = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Summary'),
        max_length=255,
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Description'),
        blank=True,
    )
    type = models.ForeignKey(
        'TicketType',
        verbose_name=_('Type'),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    ...other fields omitted...
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=_('Created'),
        default=timezone.now,
    )


class TicketType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Type'),
        max_length=255,
    )
```

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers, permissions

from tickets.models import Ticket, TicketType


class TicketSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="tickets:ticket-detail")
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'summary',
            'description',
            'type',
            ...other fields omitted...
            'created',
        )


class TicketTypeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="tickets:tickettype-detail")
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    class Meta:
        model = TicketType
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'type',
        )
```

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateAPIView

from tickets.models import Ticket, TicketType
from tickets.serializers import TicketSerializer, TicketTypeSerializer


class TicketList(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer


class TicketDetail(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer


class TicketTypeList(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = TicketType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketTypeSerializer


class TicketTypeDetail(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = TicketType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketTypeSerializer
```

Most of the things I tried related to adding lookkup_field in various places, but I guess I didn't hit on the right combination.

**EDIT:** Forgot to post my urls.py.

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from tickets import views

app_name = 'tickets'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.TicketList.as_view(), name='ticket-list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.TicketDetail.as_view(), name='ticket-detail'),
    path('types/', views.TicketTypeList.as_view(), name='tickettype-list'),
    path('types/<int:pk>/', views.TicketTypeDetail.as_view(), name='tickettype-detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It seems that, in this case, DRF isn't providing the fully-qualified view_name when trying to "reverse" to get the list of options for the field.

I added this to the TicketType serializer:

```py
    type = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        queryset=TicketType.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        view_name='tickets:tickettype-detail',
    )
```

For view_name, DRF was using "tickettype-detail".

I then added this to the TicketType model:

```py
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
```